# Prove that for every integer $n$ there exists a unique integer $m$ such that $2m + 8n = 6$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for every integer $n$ there exists a unique integer $m$ such that $2m + 8n = 6$.

My method:

Let $n$ be given. We know that $2m + 8n = 6$. Then $2m = 6 - 8n$. Thus, $m = 3 - 4n$.

I am trying to show existence. Would my next step be to plug $m$ into the original equation?

Answer (score 5):

Because the set of integers is closed under subtraction and multiplication, $3-4n\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. To show uniqueness, suppose that $m_1$ and $m_2$ are both solutions to the equation. Then $2m_1+8n=6\implies 2m_1=6-8n\implies m_1=3-4n$. But $2m_2+8n=6\implies 2m_2=6-8n\implies m_2=3-4n$, so $m_1=m_2$.

Plugging $m$ back into the original equation will not yield anything useful - only that $6=6$.

I honestly don't know if this should be more complicated than I'm making it.

Comment: I think your approach is the most easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If $\exists \ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $2x+3y = 6 = 3 \cdot 2$ then ;

$$[2x+3y] \equiv 0  \ (\textrm{mod 2}) \Rightarrow 3y \equiv 0 \ (\textrm{mod 2})$$

Recall that $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{[0],[1]\}$ and so $y$ must be a multiple of $2$.

Therefore letting $y = 2M$ we have; $x+ 3M = 3$. If we do the same argument as before modulo $3$ we have $x = 3N$ i.e;

$$N+M = 1$$

Thus given $y = 2M$ we see that $N = M-1$ i.e $x = 3(M-1)$ which says $x$ is determined by $y$ and this shows the uniqueness.